# Save User Settings ( switch Toggles ) Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, settings

[page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXt5m.png)

Lets say we have a page in PCL xamarin forms application
I want to save the settings ( toggle switch choices ) for each users :
- save them locally and remotly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [more than 80 settings to store for each user in a Xamarin forms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964437/more-than-80-settings-to-store-for-each-user-in-a-xamarin-forms-application)

Comment: dup link doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest way to implement this is by using James Montemagno's [Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin). It's available as a NuGet package, just remember to install it in all of your projects both shared and platform.

It should be pretty self-explanatory. When you install the package it already creates a helper class for you and shows you a readme file.

It works only with simple types, being: `Boolean`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `String`, `Single`(float), `Guid`, `Double`, `Decimal`, `DateTime`.

When you installed the package you get a default static class to access your settings which looks like this:

```
private static ISettings AppSettings
{
  get
  {
    return CrossSettings.Current;
  }
}
```

You can now define your settings with key/value pairs and define a default value, i.e.:

```
private const string UserNameKey = "username_key";
private static readonly string UserNameDefault = string.Empty;

private const string SomeIntKey = "int_key";
private static readonly int SomeIntDefault = 6251986;
```

And retrieve them by properties, like this:

```
public static string UserName
{
  get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault<string>(UserNameKey, UserNameDefault); }
  set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue<string>(UserNameKey, value); }
}

public static int SomeInt
{
  get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault<int>(SomeIntKey, SomeIntDefault); }
  set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue<int>(SomeIntKey, value); }
}
```

You can also use databinding in Xamarin.Forms so you don't need any redundant code. More in-depth can be read about in the documentation [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin#databinding-in-xamarinforms).

Because it is using properties etc. you could implement some code yourself to call a backend service and store the settings there as well.

Comment: thank's for your answer but i read the same answer many times ! while in my case i have 2 problems : 
- i need to save toggle switch ( on or off ) not Boolean, Int32, Int64, String, Single(float), Guid, Double, Decimal, DateTime.
- and they are more than 16 ( 80 to be more accurate )

Comment: A switch being on or off is true/false so a boolean? And you should make 80 properties then. Doesn't feel as elegant as it could be, but I'm not really sure about any other good solution which would do better. Store them in a Dictionary or something but you'll have to do a lot of managing the settings yourself that way